# Are the singular values Lipschitz smooth?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

A function $f$ is Lipschitz smooth with constant $L$ if its derivatives are Lipschitz continuous with constant $L$, in other words if for any $x$ and $y$,
$$\| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \| \leq L \| x - y \|$$.

My question is whether the functions $f_i:\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $f_i(A) = \sigma_i(A)$ are Lipschitz smooth with some constant?

*$f_i$ assigns a matrix $A$ to its $i$'th largest signular value

** I limit the discussion to the case where $A$ is a symmetric matrix with different eigenvalues.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88132/lipschitz-continuity-of-singular-values

Comment: They are not even differentiable.

Comment: @MoisheCohen. You are right. Let me re-ask the quesion, limiting the discussion to the case where $A$ is a symmetric matrix with different eigenvalues. In that case I believe I read a reference saying that they are analytic function of the matrix entries.